# Strange "SELECT" in WebSQL or not?

Tags: javascript, web-sql

I'm trying to use WebSQL using [html5rocks example](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webdatabase/todo/). All goes well until I try to do `"SELECT * FROM todo"` then there is something not clear to me. Callback returns `SQLResultSet` without `SQLResultSetRowList`. 
Code below I tried in Chrome, Background script (Chrome Extension) and Opera.

#### Step 1. Opening the database

```
 db = openDatabase("todo", "1.0", "Todo manager", 5 * 1024 * 1024);
```

#### Step 2. Creating a table

```
 db.transaction(function(tx) {
  tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
  "todo(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, todo TEXT, added_on DATETIME)", []);
 });
```

#### Step 3. Adding data to a table

```
 db.transaction(function(tx){
  var addedOn = new Date();
  tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO todo(todo, added_on) VALUES (?,?)",
    ['todo_text1', addedOn]);
 });
```

#### Step 4. Selecting data from a table

```
 db.transaction(function(tx) {
  tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM todo", [], function(tx, r){console.log(tx, r)},
    function(tx, r){console.log(tx, r)});
 });
```

Can't figure out where I am wrong.

Comment: When I run your code, the `SQLResultSetRowList` is still there, you just need to access it with `r.rows`.

Comment: Hey! Thank you very much Xymostech! I was [misled by console](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19793035/websql/select.png), it shows `SQLResultSet` with single property `{rowsAffected: 0}` and I wasn't smart enough to guess where the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Which is the question here?